# Shifting a button down

Tags: iphone, xcode, button, shift

How do I shift a button location down? I have a UISwitch when its on, which will then display some stuffs, but that would cover one of my button. How do I shift the button down so that it's not overlapped?

Comment: Drag it in Interface Builder, which you should be using.

Comment: @jtbandes No, I don't want it to be on a fixed place permanently. I want it to be shifted when its blocked by the stuffs displayed when UISwitch is ON

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the frame of the button to the new location.  For instance, this will move the button down 100 pixels:

```
myButton.frame = CGRectOffset(myButton.frame, 100.0, 0);
```